# Any solution to prevent screenshots on iOS in flutter?

Tags: ios, flutter, screenshot

I have tried the flutter_windowmanager package and it helps on android, but is there any solution to prevent screenshots in iOS app in flutter?

Comment: *tries tried    __

Answer (score 0):

there a better solution for Ios, see https://pub.dev/packages/secure_application

Comment: Does that prevent ***screenshots***? Quick look at the link does not appear to suggest it does.

Comment: I found that we can't prevent iOS from taking screenshots, we can just detect the screenshot event.